# Failed to build Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, compiling, python3

I want to install new Python version (3.6.5) on Ubuntu but get this error when compiling.

```
KeyError: 'ffi_cflags'
Makefile:596: recipe for target 'sharedmods' failed
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1
```

I issued these commands:

```
mkdir soft && cd soft
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
tar xvJf Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.5
./configure
make
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not fix your issue with compiling, but you might want to install Python 3.6.5 using a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Comment: @Melebius : Jack seems to need to install Python3.6.5. I don't know why he does not have `ffi_cflags` as a dictionary key, but using a workaround might help him to install Python3.6.5.